# Yahoo mail password recovery

Tags: account-recovery, yahoo-account

I have this situation where I can only access my yahoo e-mail account on my iPhone. However I forgot my password and I have no back-up solution to this situation; My secondary email is no longer available and I didn't set my phone up as a recovery tool. The answer to the recovery question is not working either!

I would like to make it clear that I do not want to hack an e-mail account but I want to access my e-mail from other devices (tablet, laptop etc.).

Update #1: maybe it would be a good idea for Yahoo to provide users with a contact form to actually submit this kind of problems of a phone number for assistance.

Comment: Can you explain why or how the recovery wizard is not working

Comment: I have specified that the e-mail set as a secondary e-mail is no longer available, I did not set my phone as a backup tool and the recovery question is not working also.

Comment: Why can't you change your details via the IPhone? Meaning, add a different back up email account, or add your phone or change the security question (or does it require the password to confirm the change)?

Comment: The account is set via the iPhone e-mail client and not the browser and from my know-how I cannot access security features as backup information via the client.

Answer (score 2):

Recover a Forgotten Yahoo! Mail Password

To reset your Yahoo! Mail password if you have forgotten the phrase or cannot access your account:

> - Go to the Yahoo! Password Helper page.
> - Make sure I have a problem with my password is selected.
> - Click Next.
> - Type your Yahoo! Mail email address under My Yahoo! ID is:.
>
>   - You can also enter just the user name part (what comes before, for instance, "@yahoo.com").
> - Now type confirmation code from the image or audio playback under Type the code shown.
> - Click Next.
> - If you have specified an alternate email address for recovery:
>
>   - Type your alternate email address under Send a message to my alternate email address:.
>   - Click Next.
>   - Open the email from Yahoo! with the subject "How to reset your Yahoo! password".
>   - Follow the Reset My Password link in the message.
>   - If you want to answer your secret question:
>   - Make sure Use my secret questions. is selected.
>   - Click Next.
>   - For each question:
>   - Enter the answer beneath the question.
>   - Click Next.
> - Type the desired password under New password: and Retype the password:.
> - Click Next.

You can then change this password to whatever you like (and will remember); it is best, of course, to use a strong password.