# How to unlock and change Yahoo Mail password?

Tags: yahoo-mail

I have a *Yahoo Mail* account that I forgot the password of. (I use it mostly because of Flickr.)

I tried changing it, but they have a bug that doesn't matter what password you put it you get an error:

> you can't use any part of your name in your email

I even tried using only numbers and I get the same error.

As consequence my account got blocked. I have waited the 12hs and 24hs (it tells you different amount of hours in different places), but to no avail. It is still locked. (I do recall my secret answers.)

I even managed to send them an email, but the automatic message said they will answer me to the account that is blocked!

I tried calling their customer service, but I waited 3 hours on the line and they never answered.

I tried creating a secondary account to try to send them an email, but they force you to put a mobile phone.

Has anyone ever dealt with this successfully?

---

**Update**
In the end I managed to solve this by using the Chrome or Firefox developer tools, I edited the textbox removing classes, validators and javascripts in several combinations until it worked. They never answered the phone or anything and it was really a miracle I managed to make it work this way.

Comment: Do one of these answer your question? [Yahoo mail password recovery](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/42192) [I forgot my password to my e-mail and the secondary e-mail is no longer good](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/50444)

Comment: @AlE. no, nothing seems to work. I have browsed the entire help. I even called. And all of their password recovery methods seem bugged.